# TFS code graph visualization

Tags: visual-studio-2008, graph, visualization

I wanted to know if someone know a add in\program that take a TFS team project and create a "clip" of the changes of the code\projects\size\users over time?

I think I wasn't clear enough. I will give one scenario that I mean, for example I want to see growth of the project over time. I mark a solution and it create a graph that show each project inside the solution with size as the amount of code it holds, and I can start a "movie" that show the graph update over time according to the check in to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it answer your question, but the tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) can help visualizing .NET code, and also see changes (do the diff) between 2 versions of a code base.

Comment: I tried to update the question to be a little bit clearer, I looked on the tool and it didn't seem like what I was looking for.